# getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);//error "this" is redlined

Tags: android

I am getting the following error and the "this" argument is red lined I am not able to understand the error so please help and suggest!

> Error:(52, 27) error: method initLoader in class LoaderManager cannot
>   be applied to given types; required: int,Bundle,LoaderCallbacks
>   found: int,,ScrollingActivity reason: cannot infer
>   type-variable(s) D (argument mismatch; ScrollingActivity cannot be
>   converted to LoaderCallbacks) where D is a type-variable: D extends
>   Object declared in method initLoader(int,Bundle,LoaderCallbacks)

Comment: Your activity would need to implement LoaderCallbacks for this to work.

Comment: yes sir i have implemented the LoaderCallbacks than too its showing an error!

Comment: IF that too is showing an error then you probably haven't implemented all of the functions you need to.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly due to an import mismatch of `LoaderCallbacks`. If you're using `getLoaderManager()`, your import line for `LoaderCallbacks` should be:

`android.app.LoaderCallbacks`

If you're using `getSupportLoaderManager()`, then the import should be:

`android.support.v4.app.LoaderCallbacks`

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks!